# Pandas: if Column A is blank, Column B else Column A

Tags: python, pandas

```
Current_df:

    Unnamed: 0 Div       Date      Time        HomeTeam          AwayTeam  FTHG  FTAG FTR  HTHG  HTAG HTR     Referee  Unnamed: 62  GB>2.5  GB<2.5  GBAHH  GBAHA  GBAH             HT         AT
0            0  E0 2019-08-09  20:00:00       Liverpool           Norwich     4     1   H     4     0   H    M Oliver          NaN     NaN     NaN    NaN    NaN   NaN            NaN        NaN
1            1  E0 2019-08-10  12:30:00        West Ham          Man City     0     5   A     0     1   A      M Dean          NaN     NaN     NaN    NaN    NaN   NaN            NaN        NaN
2            2  E0 2019-08-10  15:00:00     Bournemouth  Sheffield United     1     1   D     0     0   D    K Friend          NaN     NaN     NaN    NaN    NaN   NaN            NaN        NaN
3            3  E0 2019-08-10  15:00:00         Burnley       Southampton     3     0   H     0     0   D     G Scott          NaN     NaN     NaN    NaN    NaN   NaN            NaN        NaN
4            4  E0 2019-08-10  15:00:00  Crystal Palace           Everton     0     0   D     0     0   D      J Moss          NaN     NaN     NaN    NaN    NaN   NaN            NaN        NaN
5            5  E0 2019-08-10  15:00:00         Watford          Brighton     0     3   A     0     1   A    C Pawson          NaN     NaN     NaN    NaN    NaN   NaN            NaN        NaN
6            6  E0 2019-08-10  17:30:00       Tottenham       Aston Villa     3     1   H     0     1   A  C Kavanagh          NaN     NaN     NaN    NaN    NaN   NaN            NaN        NaN
7            7  E0 2019-08-11  14:00:00       Leicester            Wolves     0     0   D     0     0   D  A Marriner          NaN     NaN     NaN    NaN    NaN   NaN            NaN        NaN
8         7084  G1 2004-09-18       NaN             NaN               NaN     0     1   A     0     0   D         NaN          NaN    1.83    1.83   1.66   1.95   0.5      Ergotelis    Iraklis
9         7085  G1 2004-09-18       NaN             NaN               NaN     3     1   H     1     1   D         NaN          NaN    2.00    1.65   1.90   1.71  -0.5         Xanthi       Aris
10        7086  G1 2004-09-19       NaN             NaN               NaN     1     0   H     1     0   H         NaN          NaN    2.00    1.65   1.85   1.85   0.0     Chalkidona  Panionios
11        7087  G1 2004-09-19       NaN             NaN               NaN     1     1   D     0     0   D         NaN          NaN    1.83    1.83   1.67   1.95   0.5         Egaleo        AEK
12        7088  G1 2004-09-19       NaN             NaN               NaN     1     0   H     1     0   H         NaN          NaN    1.85    1.79   1.85   1.85   0.0      Kalamaria        OFI
13        7089  G1 2004-09-19       NaN             NaN               NaN     2     1   H     1     1   D         NaN          NaN     NaN     NaN    NaN    NaN   NaN     Olympiakos   Kalithea
14        7090  G1 2004-09-19       NaN             NaN               NaN     3     0   H     2     0   H         NaN          NaN     NaN     NaN    NaN    NaN   NaN  Panathinaikos    Ionikos


Expected df:

    Unnamed: 0 Div       Date      Time        HomeTeam          AwayTeam  FTHG  FTAG FTR  HTHG  HTAG HTR     Referee  Unnamed: 62  GB>2.5  GB<2.5  GBAHH  GBAHA  GBAH  HT  AT
0            0  E0 2019-08-09  20:00:00       Liverpool           Norwich     4     1   H     4     0   H    M Oliver          NaN     NaN     NaN    NaN    NaN   NaN NaN NaN
1            1  E0 2019-08-10  12:30:00        West Ham          Man City     0     5   A     0     1   A      M Dean          NaN     NaN     NaN    NaN    NaN   NaN NaN NaN
2            2  E0 2019-08-10  15:00:00     Bournemouth  Sheffield United     1     1   D     0     0   D    K Friend          NaN     NaN     NaN    NaN    NaN   NaN NaN NaN
3            3  E0 2019-08-10  15:00:00         Burnley       Southampton     3     0   H     0     0   D     G Scott          NaN     NaN     NaN    NaN    NaN   NaN NaN NaN
4            4  E0 2019-08-10  15:00:00  Crystal Palace           Everton     0     0   D     0     0   D      J Moss          NaN     NaN     NaN    NaN    NaN   NaN NaN NaN
5            5  E0 2019-08-10  15:00:00         Watford          Brighton     0     3   A     0     1   A    C Pawson          NaN     NaN     NaN    NaN    NaN   NaN NaN NaN
6            6  E0 2019-08-10  17:30:00       Tottenham       Aston Villa     3     1   H     0     1   A  C Kavanagh          NaN     NaN     NaN    NaN    NaN   NaN NaN NaN
7            7  E0 2019-08-11  14:00:00       Leicester            Wolves     0     0   D     0     0   D  A Marriner          NaN     NaN     NaN    NaN    NaN   NaN NaN NaN
8         7084  G1 2004-09-18       NaN             NaN               NaN     0     1   A     0     0   D         NaN          NaN    1.83    1.83   1.66   1.95   0.5 NaN NaN
9         7085  G1 2004-09-18       NaN       Ergotelis           Iraklis     3     1   H     1     1   D         NaN          NaN    2.00    1.65   1.90   1.71  -0.5 NaN NaN
10        7086  G1 2004-09-19       NaN          Xanthi              Aris     1     0   H     1     0   H         NaN          NaN    2.00    1.65   1.85   1.85   0.0 NaN NaN
11        7087  G1 2004-09-19       NaN      Chalkidona         Panionios     1     1   D     0     0   D         NaN          NaN    1.83    1.83   1.67   1.95   0.5 NaN NaN
12        7088  G1 2004-09-19       NaN          Egaleo               AEK     1     0   H     1     0   H         NaN          NaN    1.85    1.79   1.85   1.85   0.0 NaN NaN
13        7089  G1 2004-09-19       NaN       Kalamaria               OFI     2     1   H     1     1   D         NaN          NaN     NaN     NaN    NaN    NaN   NaN NaN NaN
14        7090  G1 2004-09-19       NaN      Olympiakos          Kalithea     3     0   H     2     0   H         NaN          NaN     NaN     NaN    NaN    NaN   NaN NaN NaN
```

Essentially, I want to place non null values of HT and AT to HomeTeam and AwayTeam columns

There does not seem to be a straightforward way; there are many ways I guess;

1. Create a new column with an IF HT and AT not blank and HomeTeam and
   AwayTeam blank then HT and AT else HomeTeam and AwayTeam
2. If (In column HomeTeam and AwayTeam) If HomeTeam and AwayTeam blank then HT
   and AT else HomeTeam and Away Team.

How can I go about it in pandas?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this considering df is your pandas Dataframe and you have imported NumPy as np

```
df = df.replace('', np.nan)
```

And after that apply a lambda function looking for the 'NaN' value like in the code below:

```
import pandas as pd

names = {'First_name': ['Jon','Bill','Maria','Emma']}
df = pd.DataFrame(names,columns=['First_name'])

df['name_match'] = df['First_name'].apply(lambda x: 'Match' if x == 'Bill' else 'Mismatch')

print (df)
```

Comment: How do I replace `x == 'Bill'` is not null?